# Convert pandas offset to python date

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has the handy method to_offset, in package [pandas.tseries.frequency](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py#L390), which converts a string to an offset:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
_30_days_ago = to_offset("30D")
```

How can I convert from an offset to:

- a Python date, or
- a string in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

In particular, how can I use offset to calculate dates? For example, if today is 2017-05-11, how can I use `to_offset("10D")` to get the date `2017-05-01` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need use `to_offset`:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

ts = pd.to_datetime('2017-05-11') - to_offset("10D")
print (ts)
2017-05-01 00:00:00

print (type(ts))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

For string add [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/):

```
ts_str = ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (ts_str)
2017-05-01
print (type(ts_str))
<class 'str'>
```

And for date add [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

```
ts_python_date = ts.date()
print (ts_python_date)
2017-05-01
print (type(ts_python_date))
<class 'datetime.date'>
```

---

Another solution is use [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
print (pd.to_datetime('2017-05-11') - pd.Timedelta('10D'))
#same as
#print ((pd.to_datetime('2017-05-11') - pd.to_timedelta('10D')))
2017-05-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [149]: pd.datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(days=10)
Out[149]: Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:44:38.082351')
```

you can also truncate the time:

```
In [154]: (pd.datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(days=10)).normalize()
Out[154]: Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00')
```